# How to force the order of where conditions in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

As far as I know, the "where" method in ActiveRecord doesn't grantee the order of conditions when creating the sql command with an attribute hash. For example:

```
Student.where(:classroom_id => 1, :serial_no => 10, :name => 'Allen')
# SELECT `students`.* FROM `students` WHERE `students`.`name` = 'Allen' AND `subscriptions`.`serial_no` = 10 AND `subscriptions`.`classroom_id` = 1
```

We can use "where" with an Array to force the condition format, like this:

```
Student.where(["classroom_id = ? AND serial_no = ? AND name = ?", 1, 10, 'Allen'])
# SELECT `students`.* FROM `students` WHERE (classroom_id = 1 AND serial_no = 10 AND name = 'Allen')
```

But we would lose the flexibility of using the attribute hash. Actually, we only want to force the first 2 conditions(i.e., classroom_id and serial_no) in an order.

Is there any way to force the first 2 conditions in an order and use a given hash to assign the following conditions?

**UPDATE:**

Why I care the order of conditions?

Because I use multi-column index for (classroom_id, serial_no). The index works if we use the following two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE classroom_id = 1 AND serial_no = 10 AND name = 'Allen'

SELECT * FROM students WHERE classroom_id = 1 AND name = 'Allen'
```

but would not work(or not fully utilized) with these two:

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE name = 'Allen' AND classroom_id = 1 AND serial_no = 10

SELECT * FROM students WHERE serial_no = 10 AND classroom_id = 1 AND name = 'Allen'
```

Comment: It really doesn't make a difference what order they appear in... the result will be the same.

Comment: It does matter if classroom_id and serial_no are using the multi-column index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this syntax to do what you want:

```
Student.where(:classroom_id => 1).where(:serial_no => 10).where(:name => 'Allen')

#OR

Student.where(:classroom_id => 1).where(:serial_no => 10, :name => 'Allen')
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Actually I tried this way before, but I don't know it is the best practice or not because it doesn't work if using where([:classroom_id = ?, 1]) in the first condition...I will accept this answer if there is no better one. Thanks.

Comment: +1 certainly seems a best practice to me, query chaining is one the biggest feature of rails(imho) :)

Answer (score -1):

Since when you are querying a database, you are basically dealing with sets, I would recommend you to read about [Boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations)

Answering your question, it doesn't matter the order, because you are dealing only with **AND** operation, so A **and** B **and** C is the same as C **and** A **and**  B.

So forget the order, if you are not getting the results you want, look elsewhere, because it's not the order fault.

**Update:**

Have you tried chaining where clauses like:

```
Student.where(:classroom_id => 1, :serial_no => 10).where(:name => 'Allen')
```

Comment: Just mentioned in my comment, it does matter if classroom_id and serial_no are using the multi-column index. Maybe I should write more about why I need to do this...

Comment: @SibevinWang I've updated the answer with the where chaining option.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it seems the only way to achieve my request.